# How to capture mDNS packet using mdnsjava?

Tags: java, packet-capture, mdns, mdnsjava

Basically, my network has a many device and they all broadcast the mDNS packet. I want to capture the packet and get IP address by parsing it. I tired using mdnsjava but i end up nowhere? Is there any way around for capturing mDNS packet.?

Comment: With pcap4j / jethereal perhaps ?

Comment: Can you suggest some good example for that please.?

Comment: I prefer to leave it up to you to google some relevant examples ;-) In the end it is you who needs to decide if this is the correct approach.